# Calculator App Crash when using "Enter" Key

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to write a graphical calculator, So far the calculator works, but I want to use the Key "Enter" for it to perform the operation and give the answer. For now it just crashes whenever I press `Enter`. This is the XAML code:

```
<TextBox Height="38" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"
 Margin="16,23,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="226" 
 FontSize="20" Background="Black" BorderThickness="2" Name="tb"
 Text="" KeyUp="KeyDownHandler">
```

Here is the code that handles the `Enter` key event.

```
private void KeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
     {
          result();
     }
}     

private void result()
{
     String op;
     int iOp = 0;
     if (tb.Text.Contains("+"))
     {
         iOp = tb.Text.IndexOf("+");
     }
     else if (tb.Text.Contains("-"))
     {
         iOp = tb.Text.IndexOf("-");
     }
     else if (tb.Text.Contains("*"))
     {
         iOp = tb.Text.IndexOf("*");
     }
     else if (tb.Text.Contains("/"))
     {
         iOp = tb.Text.IndexOf("/");
     }
     else
     {
         //error
     }

     op = tb.Text.Substring(iOp, 1);
     double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(tb.Text.Substring(0, iOp));
     double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(tb.Text.Substring(iOp + 1, tb.Text.Length - iOp - 2));

     if (op == "+")
     {
         tb.Text = Convert.ToString(num1 + num2);
     }
     else if (op == "-")
     {
         tb.Text = Convert.ToString(num1 - num2);
     }
     else if (op == "*")
     {
         tb.Text = Convert.ToString(num1 * num2);
     }
     else if (op == "/")
     {
         tb.Text = Convert.ToString(num1 / num2);
     }
}
```

I am beginner in C#, XAML and Visual Studio. Is this the right way of handling the Enter.key event?

This is the exception thrown:

> Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.ni.dll

Comment: Whats does the result method do? What error does the debugger throw when the app crashes?

Comment: Added the result method. It takes the string and spit it into numbers and does the math operation.

Comment: well the code works when I manually press the calculator keys... or type the operation "1+2" into the box. but only if I press the "=" button on the calc. If I use "Enter" instead of the "=" then it crashes.

Comment: Check my updated answer. It should now works with `Enter` instead of the `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(tb.Text.Substring(iOp + 1, tb.Text.Length - iOp - 2));
```

To this:

```
double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(tb.Text.Substring(iOp + 1, tb.Text.Length - iOp - 1));
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I almost died looking for the problem!! reason why it caused the crash? trying to understand what that has to do with the "Enter" key

Comment: Probably not related to the enter key. The enter key invokes the function having a bug.